# How to cut a text file using Vim

Tags: vim

How can I cut a text file using vim? For example I would like to cut the file up to position 56. So I would like to keep everything from position 1-56, and delete everything from position 57 (including 57) to the end of the line for EVERY line.

**Text file:**

```
Web Application - http://sharepoint

Url                                                     CompatibilityLevel
---                                                     ------------------
http://sharepoint                                       15
http://sharepoint/sites/appcatalog                      15
http://sharepoint/sites/devtest                         15
http://sharepoint/sites/publishing                      15
```

I can get more or less the results I want using awk:

```
$awk '{print $1}' file
```

**Results:**

```
Web

Url
---
http://sharepoint
http://sharepoint/sites/appcatalog
http://sharepoint/sites/devtest
http://sharepoint/sites/publishing
```

But say I want to split hairs and really want to keep the title. How can I technically cut this file up to position 56 using vim. Preferably within vim. Meaning I have the file open in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here are a few of them:

1. `:%s/\%>56c.//g`
2. `:%s/\%57c.*//`
3. `:%s/\v^.{56}\zs.*//`
4. `:% normal 57|D` (this one assumes `virtualedit=all` or `virtualedit=onemore`)
5. <kbd>Shift-g</kbd>`57`<kbd>|</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Shift-g</kbd><kbd>End</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (this one assumes `virtualedit=all`)

**Edit:** Adding the relevant regurgitations from the manual, as requested:

- For 1. and 2. (`:h /\%c`):

  > `\%23c`   Matches in a specific column.
  >   `\%<23c`  Matches before a specific column.
  >   `\%>23c`  Matches after a specific column.
  >       These three can be used to match specific columns in a buffer or
  >       string.  The "23" can be any column number.  The first column is 1.
  >       Actually, the column is the byte number (thus it's not exactly right
  >       for multi-byte characters).
- For 3. (`:h \zs`):

  > `\zs`     Matches at any position, and sets the start of the match there: The
  >       next char is the first char of the whole match.
- For 4. (`:h |`, `:h D`, `:h :normal`, `:h :%`, `:h 'virtualedit'`):

  > `|`                       To screen column [count] in the current line.
  >                       exclusive motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe
  >
  > `["x]D`                   Delete the characters under the cursor until the end
  >                       of the line and [count]-1 more lines [into register
  >                       x]; synonym for "d$".
  >
  > `:norm[al][!] {commands}` Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes
  >                       it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on
  >                       the command-line.  {commands} are executed like they
  >                       are typed.
  >
  > `%`               equal to `1,$` (the entire file)
  >
  > `'virtualedit'`         A comma separated list of these words:
  >           `block`       Allow virtual editing in Visual block mode.
  >           `insert`      Allow virtual editing in Insert mode.
  >           `all`         Allow virtual editing in all modes.
  >           `onemore`     Allow the cursor to move just past the end of the line
  >
  > Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is
  >       no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end
  >       of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and
  >       editing a table.
- For 5. (`:h G`, `:h CTRL-V`, `:h <End>`, `:h x`):

  > `G`                       Goto line [count], default last line, on the first
  >                       non-blank character linewise.
  >
  > `[count]CTRL-V`           Start Visual mode blockwise.
  >
  > `$` or `<End>` To the end of the line.
  >
  > `["x]x` Delete [count] characters under and after the cursor
  >                       [into register x] (not linewise).  Does the same as
  >                       "dl".

Comment: Please describe how these commands work.

Comment: @TimothyMartin Please describe what problems did you encounter understanding how they work.

Comment: Providing solutions without explanation is like giving a man a fish but not teaching him how to fish.  While the commands work those who are unfamiliar with using vim commands do not really learn anything.

Comment: @TimothyMartin In this particular case, the fishing manual is pretty comprehensive...

Comment: @Sato +1 for suggestions. In this case I'm with the OP. It would be helpful if you could add a little explanation... pretty please?

Comment: Is the following syntax `\%23c` (including before and after) vim specific? or is it regex? I cant find anything on % with regards to regex. If it is vim specific, where can I find information like that?

Comment: @jes516 There are 50+ regex dialects widely in use, mostly incompatible to one another.  `\%23c` is a Vim-specific regex.  You can find out more about Vim regexes in the manual: `:h pattern-searches`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by "position" you mean "column" one could use a regular expression

```
:%s/^\v(.{56}).*/\1/
```

Which says from the beginning of the line `^` be more like Perl (`\v`, magic) match anything `.` 56 times saving that stuff (the parens), `.*` to match the rest of the line; replace line with `\1` or what saved by the parens.

You could also more or less just call `awk`, unless filters are illegal for some reason:

```
:%!awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In vim, in order to `{print $1}` for everything except the title, try:

```
:2,$s/ .*//
```